# Drawing on a Image in C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, graphics, clipboard

I'm trying to copy an image from the clipboard onto an existing image.
Basically the existing image is 150 X 150 white coloured .jpg image. (Acting as the canvas)

I would like to know how to draw my image from clipboard onto this....

```
Image imgNew = Clipboard.GetImage(); //Getting the image in clipboard
Bitmap btnImg = new Bitmap(imgNew, 150, 100);  
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)btnImg);
g.DrawImage(btnImg, 0, 0, 150, 100);
```

In this method it is not drawing on the already existing image. Actually I'm using an Imagebox here. So the canvas is set as the imagebox's image.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want to draw it? In order to see it, you'll need to obtain a `Graphics` instance from a control or form (preferrably in the `Paint()` event), or just assign the bitmap to a Picture Box control.

Comment: I am using a 150 X 150 base image as canvas because I want my final image in 150 X 150 pixels.. Otherwise the code above is sufficient.

Comment: If you only want to draw to a bitmap, how do you know your code doesn't work fine already?

Comment: @Jonathan.. I want to draw it on the existing image in the picture box. The code which I have given here is how I'm compiling the image to be copied. "g.DrawImage(btnImg, 0, 0, 150, 100);" part doesn't draw anything now. Sorry If I couoldv'e showed u the scenario then it wld be easier to understand.. :(

Comment: Then please read my first comment.

Comment: @Jonathan. Thnx man.. It worked.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Image imgNew = Clipboard.GetImage(); //Getting the image in clipboard
Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawImage(imgNew, 0, 0, 150, 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to assign the image to the picturebox

```
pictureBox1.Image = btnImg;
```

You should use `using` to make sure allocated resources are freed when no longer needed. The full code:

```
using (Image imgNew = Clipboard.GetImage()) //Getting the image in clipboard
{
    if (imgNew != null)
    {
        Bitmap btnImg = new Bitmap(imgNew, 150, 100);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)btnImg))
            g.DrawImage(btnImg, 0, 0, 150, 100);
        pictureBox1.Image = btnImg;
    }
}
```